# How to enable netbios protocol via netsh command?

Tags: windows-xp, netbios

How can I enable netbios via the netsh command on windows XP?

Answer (score 1):

While not explicitly using netsh, there are ways to do this using wmic:

```
wmic nicconfig get caption,index,TcpipNetbiosOptions
```

Then use the index for your interface in the following command:

```
wmic nicconfig where index=x call SetTcpipNetbios 1
```

[Source](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winservercore/thread/d18bd172-e1a0-4a61-ba52-0952a1e3cabc/)

I was unable to get the first command to work on Windows 7 but executing the following and then counting (from 0) gives you the index:

```
wmic nicconfig get caption
```